# Given mean and sd, find an upper bound for a huge data set

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, computational-mathematics

[image]

Hi, can anyone help with this question, I have no idea how to do this...

Comment: What if $N$ is, say, $10$ instead, can you solve it then?

Comment: what you call average, is actually the arithmetic mean. it has certain properties. same with the RMS ( not SD) it has certain properties they want you to use those properties etc. to figure out the problem.

Comment: I wonder, does this problem have a solution? It seems to me that one can have a whole range of (large) data sets, each with the same prescribed value for the mean and the root mean square, but with different properties when we regard the fine details of the distribution. In particular the shape of the tails.

Comment: Suppose $249876$ cases have value $17.101$ and $250124$ cases have value $9.024$.  Does that meet the mean and rms values (to two decimal places)? Is it possible to do better?